# How to watch video podcasts using XBMC

Tags: podcasts, htpc, kodi

How do I configure Xbox Media Center (XBMC) to subscribe and show videos from a video podcast (aka vodcast)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a new video source and enter the address to the video podcast (the RSS-feed) with the prefix "rss://" for example:

```
rss://feeds.feedburner.com/TedtalksHD?format=xml
```

More information can be found in the [XBMC Online Manual](http://www.xbmc.org/wiki/?title=RSS_Feeds)